# What to do to keep MySQL databases running in peak performance?

Tags: database, optimization, mysql

I have a MySQL database that is continually growing.

Every once in a while I OPTIMIZE all the tables. Would this be the sort of thing I should put a on a cron job daily or weekly?

Are there any specific tasks I could set to run automatically that keeps the database in top performance?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize your tables inside database by executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_name`.`table_name` PROCEDURE ANALYSE(1, 10);
```

This will suggest `Optimal_fieldtype` to use, You have to ALTER your database so that 
optimal `field_type` has been used.

Also, You can profile your queries inorder to make sure that proper indexing has been done on a table.

I suggest you try [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) which can let you know both "Calculate Optimal Datatype" and "SQL Profiler" which will definately help you in optimizing server performance.